# ArrayFormula with the sum and multiplication of multiple columns

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I want to assemble an array formula for the following equation: `=SUM (P2; T2; V2; X2; AB2; AD2) * N2 * R2 * Z2 * AL2`.

I tried this but I was unsuccessful:

```
=ArrayFormula (SUM (P2: P; T2: T; V2: V; X2: X; AB2: AB; AD2: AD) * N2: N * R2: R * Z2: Z * AL2: AL)
```

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA((P2:P+T2:T+V2:V+X2:X+AB2:AB+AD2:AD)*N2:N*R2:R*Z2:Z*AL2:AL)
```

Comment: arrayformula does not support SUM fx

Comment: Does this mean that it does not support any arithmetic operation functions?

Comment: it does but not SUM. to do SUM in ArrayFormula you need to use MMULT which supports all 4 arithmetic operations (+-*/). so instead of `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(A1:A10, B1:B10, C1:C10))` you need to do: `=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(A1:C10*1, TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A1:C10))^0))`